# FB not defined Error on implementing Facebook logout in Django app

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, facebook

I was trying to implement facebook logout functionality for my django app. In my app, users can log in using app username or with FB username. Now i want to implement logout functionality also.
For doing that i put this code in my html page, but i am getting 'FB is not defined' error. Can somebody help me to solve this ?

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
 <script>
   FB.init({
     appId  : 'xxx',
     status : true, // check login status
     cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
     xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
   });
 </script>
    <script>

        function logout(){
            FB.getLoginStatus(handleFBSessionResponse);
            location.href = '/user_sessions/new';
        }

        // handle a session response from any of the auth related calls
        function handleFBSessionResponse(response) {
            /*
            //Check the facebook login status
            alert("handleFBSessionResponse(), "
             + "\nresponse.status="+response.status
             +" \nresponse.session="+response.session
             +" \nresponse.perms="+response.perms);
            */

            //if we do have a non-null response.session, call FB.logout(),
            //the JS method will log the user out
            //of Facebook and remove any authorization cookies
            FB.logout(handleFBSessionResponse);
        }


        </script>
        <a href="javascript:logout();">Logout</a >
```

Comment: I think you'll need to post more code.  You dont pass FB to the logout method and dont define it in the logout method.  Is it a global variable?

Comment: sorry..this is all der in my html for that page other than a text saying "User signed in "..how should i define FB ?

Comment: sorry for the ignorance..i am quite new to programming..

Comment: You are calling the method FB.getLoginStatus(arg).  This means FB must refer to an object that has such a method.  Unless you are just inventing method names on the fly then this method (and hence its object) should be defined somewhere. Where is the getLoginStatus function defined?

Comment: i have edited my code above.. i have added a js file which i guess includes all the FB methods..i am not sure though,.Can u clear my doubt now ? what should i do to make it working from here.

Comment: now the error shown in FB.Connect is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it working with this

```
<a href="http://m.facebook.com/logout.php?confirm=1&next=http://10.1.0.90:8080/registrationForm" >Sign Out</a>
```